# Command Line Arguments - Ruby/Eclipse

Tags: ruby, eclipse

I have `if __FILE__ == $0` and want to run my code inside it. I want to run command line arguments and in eclipse I did that by placing script arguments in run config. My question is why is my code within the `if __FILE__ == $0` not running?

How my code looks like condensed

```
def main
  if __FILE__ == $0
    # do stuff
    if ARGV.size == 1
      puts "test"
    else
      puts "Error: No file specified"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was simply not calling main, I assumed it would automatically be called and that was my mistake.